# Setting up Apache2 VHost

Tags: apache, ubuntu, vhosts, httpforbiddenhandler

I'm attempting to setup a apache2 vhost in the latest version of Ubuntu and i keep getting a "Forbidden" when trying to access the page.

I have setup a folder for this new site under
`/root/websites/panel.joosh.eu/www`
And this has the owner/group of `root:root` so i can edit it and permissions of 644

This is my vhost file in `sites-avaliable` (yes i also enabled it)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName panel.joosh.eu

    ServerAdmin josh@joosh.eu
    DocumentRoot /root/websites/panel.joosh.eu/www

    <Directory /root/websites/panel.joosh.eu/www>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog /root/websites/panel.joosh.eu/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /root/websites/panel.joosh.eu/logs/access.log combined
```

Ive tried everything but i still get forbidden, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `/root/websites/panel.joosh.eu/www` permission was wrong, I guess it should be 755.

Comment: still forbidden. i gave it all the same permissions as the default /var/www holder

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /root/websites/panel.joosh.eu/www
```

your permission is wrong

[Understanding and Using File Permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)

move your project folder to /var/www/html   and try